# How to properly make a mouse listener on a game board to put chess

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing my summer project, which is about a Reversi game by implementing the AI algorithms. I am so struggling with the GUI building section by using the JavaFX. I have set a mouse clicked event on an 8x8 board, when user click any block on the board, a chess piece will be put on the specified position. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this, even the main pane showed up, but the piece still cannot show up. Following are my code. the setpiece method is in the ReversiBoard class. Thanks.

the following is the main class

```
    package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

/**
 * @author Zibo Wang 
 * the main class is the main entrance of the GUI
 *
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    public static ReversiBoard[][] RevBoard = new ReversiBoard[8][8];
    //public static ReversiAI robot = new ReversiAI();
    public static boolean AIPlay = true;
    public static boolean AIPiece = false;
    public static char whoseTurn = ' ';
    public static Circle[][] arrayCircle = new Circle[8][8];
    public static int step = 0;
    public int WIDTH = 65;
    public static TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    public static Pane mainPane = new Pane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
//          for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//              for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
//                  Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(WIDTH, WIDTH);
//                  rectangle1.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);
//                  rectangle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
//                  Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(WIDTH, WIDTH);
//                  rectangle2.setFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
//                  rectangle2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
//                  if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
//                      grid.add(rectangle1, i, j);
//                  } else {
//                      grid.add(rectangle2, i, j);
//                  }
//              }
//          }
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    grid.add(RevBoard[i][j] = new ReversiBoard(i, j), i, j);
            grid.setLayoutX(65);
            grid.setLayoutY(50);

            /*
             * inserting a background image of the GUI
             */
            ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView();
            Image image1 = new Image(test.class.getResourceAsStream("/pictures/Wood_3888x2592.jpg"));
            selectedImage.setImage(image1);
            selectedImage.setFitHeight(650);
            selectedImage.setFitWidth(1060);

            /*
             * drawing a list of buttons, and add them into the VBox, which will be located
             * at the right side of the main pane
             */
            BoardController controller = new BoardController(null, null, null, null);
            VBox vBox = new VBox(50);
            vBox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 625, 625));
            vBox.setLayoutY(150);
            vBox.getChildren().addAll(controller.getBtSet(), controller.getBtStart(), controller.getBtSurrender(),
                    controller.getBtExit());

            /*
             * Drawing a textArea, defining the font size as 16, the max width and the max
             * height, and drop it at the right hand side of the main pane,
             */
            textArea.setWrapText(true);
            textArea.setFont(new Font(15));
            textArea.setMaxWidth(250);
            textArea.setMinHeight(500);
            textArea.setLayoutX(740);
            textArea.setLayoutY(75);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.insertText(0, "Press the 'Start Game' button to strat the game!" + '\n' + '\n');

            //recall the five function defined methods from the BoardController class
            controller.settingButton(null);
            controller.startButton(null);
            controller.surrenderButton(null);
            controller.exitButton(null);
            controller.boardReset(null);

            /*
             * set a main pain which is used to contain the all GUI elements
             */
            //Pane mainPane = new Pane();
            //mainPane.getChildren().addAll(selectedImage, grid, vBox, textArea);
            mainPane.getChildren().addAll(grid, vBox, textArea);

            Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 1050, 650);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome to AI Reversi");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public static void gameStart() {
        textArea.insertText(0, "Game Start！" + '\n' + '\n');
    }

    public static void whiteWin() {
        textArea.insertText(0, "White piece wins！" + '\n' + '\n');
    }

    public static void blackWin() {
        textArea.insertText(0, "Black piece wins！" + '\n' + '\n');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> the following is the BoardController

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author Zibo Wang this BoardController class mainly contains all implemented
 *         functions for the buttons
 */
public class BoardController {

    private Button btSet;
    private Button btStart;
    private Button btSurrender;
    private Button btExit;

    private Alert startConfirmWindow = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
            "The game has not ended yet, are you going to start a new game?");
    private Alert setConfirmWindow = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    private Alert surrenderConfirmWindow = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you going to surrender?");
    private Alert exitConfirmWindow = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you going to exit the game?");
    private Alert winnerWindow = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);

    Main method = new Main();

    public BoardController(Button btSet, Button btStart, Button btSurrender, Button btExit) {
        this.btSet = new Button("Setting");
        this.btStart = new Button("Start Game");
        this.btSurrender = new Button("Surrender");
        this.btExit = new Button("Finish Game");
    }

    public Button getBtSet() {
        return btSet;
    }

    public void setBtSet(Button btSet) {
        this.btSet = btSet;
    }

    public Button getBtStart() {
        return btStart;
    }

    public void setBtStart(Button btStart) {
        this.btStart = btStart;
    }

    public Button getBtSurrender() {
        return btSurrender;
    }

    public void setBtSurrender(Button btSurrender) {
        this.btSurrender = btSurrender;
    }

    public Button getBtExit() {
        return btExit;
    }

    public void setBtExit(Button btExit) {
        this.btExit = btExit;
    }

    /*
     * this method defines the implemented function of the setting button
     */
    public void settingButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        // game setting button function
        btSet.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (Main.whoseTurn == ' ') {
                Stage settingStage = new Stage();
                Pane settingPane = new Pane();

                // group1 is responsible to radio button 1 and 2
                ToggleGroup group1 = new ToggleGroup();
                // group2 is responsible to the option1 label
                ToggleGroup group2 = new ToggleGroup();
                ToggleGroup group3 = new ToggleGroup();

                Label option1 = new Label("Game Battle Mode");
                Label option2 = new Label("AI Battle Setting");
                Label option3 = new Label("Game Difficulty");
                option1.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px");
                option1.setLayoutX(30);
                option1.setLayoutY(15);
                option2.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px");
                option2.setLayoutX(30);
                option2.setLayoutY(100);
                option3.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 16px");
                option3.setLayoutX(30);
                option3.setLayoutY(190);

                // adding the radio buttons on the new stage, the following part is for the
                // "Game Battle Mode" setting
                // default selection is set for the AI Battle
                RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton("AI Battle");
                RadioButton radio2 = new RadioButton("Players Battle");
                radio1.setLayoutX(50);
                radio1.setLayoutY(50);
                radio2.setLayoutX(200);
                radio2.setLayoutY(50);
                // adding the radio1 and radio2 buttons into the toggle group1
                radio1.setToggleGroup(group1);
                radio2.setToggleGroup(group1);
                radio1.setSelected(true);
                Line divLine1 = new Line(0, 80, 350, 80);
                divLine1.setStrokeWidth(2f);

                // adding the radio buttons on the new stage, the following part is for the "AI
                // Battle Mode" setting
                // default selection is set for the PC side takes the white chess piece
                RadioButton radio3 = new RadioButton("PC - White piece");
                RadioButton radio4 = new RadioButton("PC - Black piece");
                radio3.setLayoutX(50);
                radio3.setLayoutY(130);
                radio4.setLayoutX(200);
                radio4.setLayoutY(130);
                radio3.setToggleGroup(group2);
                radio4.setToggleGroup(group2);
                radio3.setSelected(true);
                Line divLine2 = new Line(0, 165, 350, 165);
                divLine2.setStrokeWidth(2f);

                // adding the radio buttons on the new stage, the following part is for the
                // "Game Difficulty" setting
                RadioButton radio5 = new RadioButton("Simple");
                RadioButton radio6 = new RadioButton("Regular");
                RadioButton radio7 = new RadioButton("Complex");
                radio5.setLayoutX(50);
                radio5.setLayoutY(220);
                radio6.setLayoutX(200);
                radio6.setLayoutY(220);
                radio7.setLayoutX(50);
                radio7.setLayoutY(250);
                radio5.setToggleGroup(group3);
                radio6.setSelected(true);
                radio6.setToggleGroup(group3);
                radio7.setToggleGroup(group3);
                Line divLine3 = new Line(0, 280, 350, 280);
                divLine3.setStrokeWidth(2f);

                // inserting an background image of the selection window
                ImageView bgImage = new ImageView();
                Image image1 = new Image(test.class
                        .getResourceAsStream("/pictures/chessboard-perspective-background-vector_57911-3.jpg"));
                bgImage.setImage(image1);
                bgImage.setFitHeight(400);
                bgImage.setFitWidth(350);
                bgImage.setLayoutX(0);
                bgImage.setLayoutY(60);

                // adding two buttons at the bottom of the setting pane
                // close button is used to close the window, confirm button is used to confirm
                // all player's selection
                Button cancelBt = new Button("Cancel");
                Button confirmBt = new Button("Confirm");
                cancelBt.setLayoutX(90);
                cancelBt.setLayoutY(315);
                confirmBt.setLayoutX(190);
                confirmBt.setLayoutY(315);

                // defining function of the cancel button, which enable user to close the
                // setting board
                cancelBt.setOnAction(event2 -> {
                    settingStage.close();
                });

                // defining function of the confirm button, clicking the button to change the
                // game parameters
                confirmBt.setOnAction(event3 -> {
                    if (radio1.isSelected() == true) {
                        Main.AIPlay = true;
                        radio1.setSelected(true);
                    } else if (radio2.isSelected() == true) {
                        Main.AIPlay = false;
                        radio2.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    if (radio3.isSelected() == true) {
                        Main.AIPiece = true;
                        radio3.setSelected(true);
                    } else if (radio4.isSelected() == true) {
                        Main.AIPiece = false;
                        radio4.setSelected(true);
                    }
                    settingStage.close();
                });

                settingPane.getChildren().addAll(bgImage, option1, radio1, radio2, divLine1, option2, radio3, radio4,
                        divLine2, option3, radio5, radio6, radio7, divLine3, cancelBt, confirmBt);
                Scene scene = new Scene(settingPane, 350, 400);
                settingStage.setScene(scene);
                settingStage.setTitle("Game Setting");
                settingStage.show();
                settingStage.setResizable(false);
            } else {
                setConfirmWindow.setHeaderText(null);
                setConfirmWindow.setContentText("Please finsih this game first, then doing the game setting change");
                setConfirmWindow.showAndWait();
            }

        });
    }

    /*
     * this method defines the implemented function of the start button
     */
    public void startButton(ActionEvent event) {
        btStart.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (Main.whoseTurn == ' ') {
                startConfirmWindow.setTitle("Game Start!");
                startConfirmWindow.setHeaderText(null);
                Optional<ButtonType> result = startConfirmWindow.showAndWait();
                if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
                    boardReset(event);
            } else {
                boardReset(event);
            }

        });
    }

    /*
     * this method defines the implemented function of the surrender button
     */
    public void surrenderButton(ActionEvent event) {
        btSurrender.setOnAction(e -> {
            surrenderConfirmWindow.setTitle("Surrender");
            surrenderConfirmWindow.setHeaderText(null);
            // if the player takes the black piece, surrender window shows the white piece
            // wins
            if (Main.whoseTurn == 'B') {
                Optional<ButtonType> computerWin = surrenderConfirmWindow.showAndWait();
                if (computerWin.isPresent() && computerWin.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                    Main.textArea.insertText(0, "White piece wins！" + '\n' + '\n');
                    Main.whiteWin();
                    winnerWindow.setContentText("White piece wins！！！");
                    winnerWindow.setHeaderText(null);
                    winnerWindow.showAndWait();
                }
            } else if (Main.whoseTurn == 'W') {
                Optional<ButtonType> computerWin = surrenderConfirmWindow.showAndWait();
                if (computerWin.isPresent() && computerWin.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                    Main.textArea.insertText(0, "Black piece wins！" + '\n' + '\n');
                    Main.blackWin();
                    winnerWindow.setContentText("Black piece wins！！！");
                    winnerWindow.setHeaderText(null);
                    winnerWindow.showAndWait();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * this method defines the implemented function of the exit button
     */
    public void exitButton(ActionEvent event) {
        btExit.setOnAction(e -> {
            exitConfirmWindow.setTitle("Exit the Othello");
            exitConfirmWindow.setHeaderText(null);

            Optional<ButtonType> result = exitConfirmWindow.showAndWait();
            // press the confirm button to exit the whole system
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * this method defines the function to reset the whole Reversi board
     */
    public void boardReset(ActionEvent event) {
        Main.gameStart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Main.RevBoard[i][j].getChildren().remove(Main.arrayCircle[i][j]);
                Main.RevBoard[i][j].piece = ' ';
            }
        Main.whoseTurn = ' ';
        Main.step = 0;

        //if the game is in AI battle mode, computer will pre-place four (2 for each colour)
        //at the middle section of the Reversi board
        if (Main.AIPiece == true) {
            Main.RevBoard[3][3].setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, 3, 3, true);
            Main.RevBoard[4][3].setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, 4, 3, true);
            Main.RevBoard[3][4].setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, 3, 4, true);
            Main.RevBoard[4][3].setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, 4, 3, true);
            Main.whoseTurn = 'W';
        }
    }
}
```

the following is the MyPiece class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class MyPiece extends Circle {

    MyPiece(){      

    }

    //setting the radius, colour and shadow effect for the piece
    MyPiece(int radius, Color color){
        super.setRadius(radius);
        super.setStroke(color);
        super.setFill(color);
        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
        ds.setOffsetX(3.0);
        super.setEffect(ds);
    }

}

package application;

import java.util.List;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
```

the following is the ReversiBoard class, mouse click event is defined at here

```
public class ReversiBoard extends Pane {

    //B means black piece, W means white piece
    public char piece = 'B';
    public int playerStep;//used to count the piece steps
    private Alert gameWinner = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    private MyPiece circle = null;
    //private Media moveSong = new Media(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("put.mp3").toString());
    //private Media winSong = new Media(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("win.wav").toString());

    public ReversiBoard () {

    }

    public ReversiBoard(int x, int y) {
        setStyle("-fx-border-color:black");
        this.setPrefSize(65, 65);
        this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            handleMouseClick(x, y);
        });
    }

    public void handleMouseClick(int x, int y) { 

//      if (piece == ' ' && Main.whoseTurn != ' ' && Main.AIPlay == false) {
            setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, x, y,true);
//          //Main.textArea.insertText(0, "Evaluate:" + Main.robot.Evaluate(x, y, Main.whoseTurn) + " ");
//          
//          if (judge(Main.whoseTurn, x, y) == true)
//              printWinner();
//          else
//              Main.whoseTurn = (Main.whoseTurn == 'B') ? 'W' : 'B';
////            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(moveSong);
////            mediaPlayer.setVolume(50);
////            mediaPlayer.play();
//      }

        //if AI is true, it is in the AI battle mode
//      if (piece == ' ' && Main.whoseTurn != ' ' && Main.AIPlay == true) {
//          if (Main.whoseTurn == ' ') {
//              setPiece(Main.whoseTurn, x, y,true);
                //Main.textArea.insertText(0, "Evaluate:" + Main.robot.Evaluate(x, y, Main.whoseTurn) + " ");
//              if (judge(Main.whoseTurn, x, y) == true)
//                  printWinner();
//              else
//                  Main.whoseTurn = (Main.whoseTurn == 'B') ? 'W' : 'B';
//              MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(moveSong);
//              mediaPlayer.setVolume(50);
//              mediaPlayer.play();
//          }
//          //若whoseTurn不为空 即未分出胜负，则执行搜索函数，根据人下的子，搜索AI的下一步落子
//          if (Main.whoseTurn != ' ')
//              Main.robot.search(x,y);         
//      }
    }

    public void setPiece(char c, int x, int y, boolean flag) {
        piece = c;
        MyPiece circle = null;
        int row = x + 1;
        int column = y + 1;
        Main.step++;
        Main.RevBoard[x][y].playerStep = Main.step;
        if (piece == 'B') {
            circle = new MyPiece(30, Color.BLACK);
            //output the accurate piece positions in the text area
            if(flag==true)
            Main.textArea.insertText(0, "step:" + Main.step + " black piece:column" + column + ",row" + row + '\n' + '\n');
        } else if (piece == 'W') {
            circle = new MyPiece(30, Color.WHITE);
            if(flag==true)
            Main.textArea.insertText(0, "step:" + Main.step + " white piece:column" + column + ",row" + row + '\n' + '\n');
        }
         //bind the piece at the centre of each block
        circle.centerXProperty().bind(Main.RevBoard[x][y].widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(Main.RevBoard[x][y].heightProperty().divide(2));
        Main.RevBoard[x][y].getChildren().add(circle);
        Main.RevBoard[x][y].piece = c;
        Main.arrayCircle[x][y] = circle;
    }

    public boolean judge (char whoseTurn, int x, int y) {
        return false;

    }

    public int checkCount(char whoseTurn, int x, int y, int xChange, int yChange) {
        return yChange;

    }

    public void printWinner() {

    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you could narrow your code samples to the minimum relating to your question.

Comment: TL;DR; [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Please do not dump the whole application here, asking ask to debug the whole lot. Instead prepare an [mcve]. mcve should demonstrate the **problem**, and **not** your application. I find mcve a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/ChessFX